# Manage Unix rights reading dynamic field in a csv file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, csv

i'm currently stuck with a bash script that should be able to manage permission on files and directories at the end of the processing part.

Actually i have 4 components:

- the main script which source .conf file and libs (.sh), process things, and call a function "ApplyPermissionFromCSVFile" with a .csv file as argument at the end, to ensure that rights are correctly set. This function should handle the job for managing permission on files
- a script called "permission_lib.sh" which contains several functions, including the "ApplyPermissionFromCSVFile" one. This script is SOURCED at the begining of main script
- a .conf file which contains some path defined as variables which is SOURCED at the beginning of main script
- a .csv file containing paths (including "dynamic path", which refer to variables defined in conf file) for files and directories which is READ by the ApplyPermissionFromCSVFile function

At the moment, the main script runs correctly, is able to source both conf file and lib file but when i put some debug point inside the "ApplyPermissionFromCSVFile", it appears that "dynamic path" is not interpreted by bash.

Extract of Main Script:

```
######################################### 
includes 
##################################################

# this section can _almost_ be copied as-is ;-)

nameOfThisScript=$(basename "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
directoryOfThisScript="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"


configFile="$directoryOfThisScript/$nameOfThisScript.conf"
functionsFile="$directoryOfThisScript/safeScriptsFunctions.sh"
permissionLib="$directoryOfThisScript/permission_lib.sh"

permissionFile="$directoryOfThisScript/$nameOfThisScript.permissionFile.csv"

for fileToSource in "$configFile" "$functionsFile" "$permissionLib"; do
        source "$fileToSource" 2>/dev/null || {
                echo "File '$fileToSource' not found"
                exit 1
                }
done
#Main Loop to read CSV File is called in permissionLib.sh
ApplyPermissionFromCSVFile $permissionFile
```

Extract of conf file (real filename replaced for exemple):

```
totovariable="/usr/local"
tatavariable="$totovariable/bin"
```

Extract of csv file:

```
$totovariable;someuser;somegroup;0600
$tatavariable;someuser;somegroup;0600
```

Extract of permission lib file:

```
function ApplyPermissionFromCSVFile {
        local csvFileName="$1"
        local fieldNumberFileName=1
        local fieldNumberOwner=2
        local fieldNumberGroupOwner=3
        local fieldNumberPermissions=4

        while read csvLine
        do
                fileName=$(getFieldFromCsvLine "$fieldNumberFileName" "$csvLine")
                fileOwner=$(getFieldFromCsvLine "$fieldNumberOwner" "$csvLine")
                fileGroupOwner=$(getFieldFromCsvLine "$fieldNumberGroupOwner" "$csvLine")
                filePermissions=$(getFieldFromCsvLine "$fieldNumberPermissions" "$csvLine")
                permissionArray[0,0]="$fileName|$fileOwner|$fileGroupOwner|$filePermissions"
                echo "${permissionArray[0,0]}"
        done < "$csvFileName"
}

getFieldFromCsvLine() {
        csvFieldSeparator=';'
        fieldNumber="$1"
        csvLine="$2"
        echo "$csvLine" | cut -d "$csvFieldSeparator" -f "$fieldNumber"
}
```

Don't bother for the fact that the loop overwrite value at each iterations, it's not the purpose here (but optionnal answer :p).

Which output results:

```
$totovariable|someuser|somegroup|0600
$tatavariable|someuser|somegroup|0600

Changing owner to someuser:somegroup for file $tatavariable
chown: cannot access '$tatavariable': No such file or directory
Changing permissions to 0600 for file $tatavariable
chmod: cannot access '$tatavariable': No such file or directory
```

After some investigations an research, it seems normal as:

- conf file is SOURCED (by main script)
- lib file is SOURCED (by main script)
- csv file is not SOURCED but READ (by function in lib). So bash consider the variables contents as "pure-string", and not variables

The issue, is that i can't clearly see how and where i should replace the "pure-string" variable by its value (defined in .conf file and sourced by main script): at the main script level ? at the lib level with global variables ?

Actual solutions that i've found:

- sed substitute
- use eval

Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: `how and where` - when and where do you want to replace it, before use. I would change the notation to use `@string@` markers for variables and replace them using `sed 's/@var1@/'"$var1"'/'` before reading, using eval and storing `$variable` notation inside a csv file looks strange.

Comment: @KamilCuk, thx for your reply on sed solution (not test but i'm sure it'll work). I managed to solve my issue using "eval" which i think is not a clean way to proceed.
here what i've added before end of while loop
fileName=`eval echo "$fileName"`

I've read on stackoverflow different threads related, and people don't agree on the "right" way to do it: both using eval or shell expansion seems evil....

Answer (score 0):

Solution used:

```
fileName=eval echo "$fileName"
```

As the pathes in .csv file may contain "$" Symbol, Bash parameter expansion will not work in every case.

Exemple: 
with the following csv content:

```
$tatavariable;someuser;somegroup;0600
$totovariable/thisotherfile.txt;someuser;somegroup;0660
$totovariable;someuser;somegroup;0600
/home/someuser/lolzy.txt;someuser;somegroup;0666
```

And the following conf file:

```
totovariable="/home/someuser/fack"
tatavariable="$totovariable/thisfile.txt"
```

The following bash code (based on eval which is not highly recommended in most case) will work on every case (containing $ symbol or not):

```
#!/bin/bash

#########################
# Function
#########################

getFieldFromCsvLine() {
        local csvFieldSeparator=';'
        local fieldNumber="$1"
        local csvLine="$2"
        echo "$csvLine" | cut -d "$csvFieldSeparator" -f "$fieldNumber"
}

#########################
#Core Script
#########################

source configFile.conf

csvFileName="permissionFile.csv"
fieldNumberFileName=1
fieldNumberOwner=2
fieldNumberGroupOwner=3
fieldNumberPermissions=4

while read csvLine
do
        fileName=$(getFieldFromCsvLine "$fieldNumberFileName" "$csvLine")
        fileOwner=$(getFieldFromCsvLine "$fieldNumberOwner" "$csvLine")
        fileGroupOwner=$(getFieldFromCsvLine "$fieldNumberGroupOwner" "$csvLine")
        filePermissions=$(getFieldFromCsvLine "$fieldNumberPermissions" "$csvLine")

        #Managing Variables used as 'Dynamic path'
        fileName=$(eval echo "$fileName")
        echo "Content of \$fileName is $fileName"

done < "$csvFileName"
```

Results:

```
[someuser@SAFEsandbox:~]$ ./simpletest.sh
Content of $fileName is /home/someuser/fack/thisfile.txt
Content of $fileName is /home/someuser/fack/thisotherfile.txt
Content of $fileName is /home/someuser/fack
Content of $fileName is /home/someuser/lolzy.txt
```

Whereas the following bash code (base on bash parameters expansion) will throw errors:

```
#!/bin/bash

#########################
# Function
#########################

getFieldFromCsvLine() {
        local csvFieldSeparator=';'
        local fieldNumber="$1"
        local csvLine="$2"
        echo "$csvLine" | cut -d "$csvFieldSeparator" -f "$fieldNumber"
}

#########################
#Core Script
#########################

source configFile.conf

csvFileName="permissionFile.csv"
fieldNumberFileName=1
fieldNumberOwner=2
fieldNumberGroupOwner=3
fieldNumberPermissions=4

while read csvLine
do
        fileName=$(getFieldFromCsvLine "$fieldNumberFileName" "$csvLine")
        fileOwner=$(getFieldFromCsvLine "$fieldNumberOwner" "$csvLine")
        fileGroupOwner=$(getFieldFromCsvLine "$fieldNumberGroupOwner" "$csvLine")
        filePermissions=$(getFieldFromCsvLine "$fieldNumberPermissions" "$csvLine")

        #Managing Variables used as 'Dynamic path'
        fileName=${!fileName}
        echo "Content of \$fileName is $fileName"

done < "$csvFileName"
```

Behaviour example when .csv contains $ symbol:

```
[someuser@SAFEsandbox:~]$ ./simpletest.sh
./simpletest.sh: line 35: $tatavariable: bad substitution
```

Behaviour example when you remove the $ symbol in .csv file, but there is still incremental path notions in it:

```
[someuser@SAFEsandbox:~]$ ./simpletest.sh
Content of $fileName is /home/someuser/fack/thisfile.txt
./simpletest.sh: line 35: totovariable/thisotherfile.txt: bad substitution
```

Using bash parameter expansion (which is recommended in most case) is not easy here, because it forces to manage 2 cases in the script:

- path containing a leading $ or serveral $ (contatenated variables paths)
- path not containing a leading $ or serveral $ (contatenated variables paths)

Regards